# How to develop an Opengeo Suite Client SDK with Eclipse?

Tags: sdk, eclipse

I have a problem in developing an Client SDK application with Eclipse, maybe someone already do this.

I started by creating a new application with the Client SDK by following the tutorial :
http://suite.opengeo.org/docs/apps/clientsdk.html

Then, I managed to debug the application. Now, i want to go on developing by using the Eclipse IDE.
So I created a new project, imported code source from the application I've just created with the suite-sdk command from tutorial.

In my index.html file, I change the line like this :

```
<!-- app resources -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/app/app.js"></script>
```

Then, I run the application. Error on Firebug appears :

```
ReferenceError: gxp is not defined
var app = new gxp.Viewer({
```

It seems like the ** @require widgets/Viewer.js* line isn't read.

```
/**
 * Add all your dependencies here.
 *
 * @require widgets/Viewer.js
 */

var app = new gxp.Viewer({
```

Subsequently the buildjs.cfg file isn't take into account : this file contains the beginning path to the Viewer.js file : /openGeo/src/gxp/script/widgets/Viewer.js.

```
[app.js]
root = 
    src/openlayers/lib
    src/geoext/lib
    src/gxp/script
```

I really don't know how to solve this problem, maybe it's not due to these file...

Thanks for advance for any help.

Helena

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run an SDK app directly from the directory structure. You need to run

```
$ suite-sdk debug <yourapp>
```

from the console. You can leave this running, it will pick up your changes. The only exception is that if you add dependencies (`@require ...`), you have to Ctrl-C and restart.